# Can I get local date and time in Calendar object using State Code , GMT Offset and day light saving information?

Tags: java, date, calendar, localtime, localdate

I am creating an application  which gets the local date and time of a person in a Calendar object. I have the following information:

> State Code
>   GMT offset
>   Day light saving information

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

// I have the GMTOffset information available to me

```
LocalDateTime gmtToLocal,gmtTime ;
gmtTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
gmtToLocal = gmtTime.plusHours(GMTOffset);
```

Comment: what is your problem and where is your code?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the troublesome old legacy date-time classes (`Calendar`) with the modern java.time classes (`LocalDateTime`). **Don't.** Stick to the java.time classes exclusively.

A `LocalDateTime` has no time zone info, that is its purpose. So it does *not* represent a moment on the timeline. And it is of no use for the purpose of your Question.

You said you have a given offset-from-UTC. So you want a `OffsetDateTime` with a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Current moment in UTC.
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes( 5 , 30 );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.atOffset( offset );
```

As a shortcut, you can skip getting the `Instant`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( offset );
```

Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time cannot be handled by a mere offset-from-UTC. For that you need a time zone. A zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling those anomalies, past and present. Use a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow for many postings.

I have no idea what "State Code" means in your Question. If you mean the state or province within a country, that does *not* map to a time zone directly in all cases, so it is of no use.

Please search and study Stack Overflow before posting. These issues have been covered many times already.